# Laravel: Load specific column from model which alos includes eager loaded column

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to load only specific column from a modal which also includes eager loaded column
I want something like this

```
UserModel::select('userid', 'locationid', 'username', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'subRoleName.*')
                        ->with('subRoleName')
                        ->get();
```

But I'm getting this error `Unknown column 'subRoleName' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can eager load only specific columns from relationships. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> You may not always need every column from the relationships you are
> retrieving. For this reason, Eloquent allows you to specify which
> columns of the relationship you would like to retrieve:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author:id,name')->get();
```

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column and
> any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to
> retrieve.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
UserModel::select('userid', 'locationid', 'username', 'firstname', 'lastname')
    ->with('subRoleName:id,column2,column3')
    ->get();
```

But as the documentation says be careful to always include the id and the relevant foreign keys, otherwise it won't be able to load the relationship properly.